# dataGridView number rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make the signature of the DataGridView lines in Visual Studio 2017 I do the same as I found on the Internet, but nothing works.

The matrix is loaded from DataTable and if I try to change the signature of a line before assignment of a source at DataGridView the program considers that lines still are not present and produces an error with an index and if I try to do it after then it simply does not change anything.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
    {
        matrix.Rows.Add();
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = i;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the “i” value to a string? `dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = i.ToString();`… this will show the row numbers as you describe however you may have to do something else if the user is allowed to add/delete rows in the grid as this will not update the new row number unless you loop through the grid again. It is unclear if the users are allowed to add/delete rows.